# Auto-scroll Listbox based on TextBox text

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, autoscroll

In WPF and MVVM pattern, I have a `TextBox` and a `ListBox`. The `ListBox` is bound to a collection of items using a `DataTemplate`. The default count for this collection is about 50 or so.

What I wanted to achieve is a filter-like action. If it's possible, I wouldn't like to change the list view or anything like that, but simply to **scroll to the item corresponding to the** `TextBox` **match, preferably without selecting it.**

I've seen some examples and solutions using `CollectionView` and `Filter` (couldn't get it to work btw), and some using auto-scroll to the end of the list or to a new added item, but none specific to my case.

My `Listbox` is structured as follows:

```
<ListBox IsTextSearchEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="6,49,0,0" Name="lbObjectA" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:Dto}">
                        <StackPanel Height="20" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="0,3,0,0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```